# How to bypass old cached files using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, caching

I have created this **.htaccess** in my LAMP environment to cache the dynamic files and it works pretty well in my project. It can bypass the cache for some specific urls (content, admin, api etc) and for POST method.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content|/admin|/accounts|/api$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*mycookiename.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/content/cache/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "/content/cache/$1.html" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

I want to add one other feature. I want to bypass this rule (caching rule) if the cached file is older than required time (example bypass cached file if older than 1 hour).

How can i check from .htaccess for file modification time and use that information on my rules above to bypass caching?

This task is very easy in PHP using file_exists, filemtime and file_get_contents but if is possible I want also to bypass PHP for caching method :(